# rails ajax form action re-write route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have a rails app that does a continual save every time you click out of one of the input fields.  You start at /posts/new.  Once you write something and click out of the input, the form submits, via ajax.  The form attributes of /posts/new are then changed to the form attributes of /post/1/edit (1 can be any number).  And, the url is update to /post/1/edit (again, 1 can be any number).

When the form is submitted again, with the /post/1/edit and updated form attributes, I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/posts/4"
```

In the google chrome console, I get the following error:

```
POST http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/1 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my code.

/app/asset/javascripts/posts.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new_post').on('focusout', function(ev) {
    $('.new_post').submit();
  });

  $('.edit_post').on('focusout', function(ev) {
    $('.edit_post').submit();
  });
});
```

/app/controllers/post_controller.rb, /app/models/post.rb and /config/routes.rb are the controller, model and routes generated from scaffold of post.

app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also, a few more thing.

1) If i just go to /post/1/edit, make an edit and click out of the input field; there is no routing error.

2) The generated html after the ajax update of posts/new to the form action and the generated html for the post/1/edit page are identical.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing a PUT to update, the code is doing POST request so unless you include _method: PUT then it is not a recognised route.

Comment: I thought I tried that solution but I must have implemented it incorrectly, because on changing the method to "put" it worked.

Thanks!